# FabricJS problems with remove activeobject

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm able to remove objects from my canvas, like so:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
       if (event.key === "Delete") {
           var currentlySelected = _fabricCanvas.getActiveObject();
           if (currentlySelected) {
               _fabricCanvas.remove(currentlySelected);
           }
       }
    });
```

The problem is; I have press delete twice.  The first time I press it, the corner selection points vanish, then if I reselect the object and press delete again, it is removed.

The deletion event triggers a 'selection:cleared' event, so I'm a bit confused as to why this is doing it.  All of the objects on the canvas are 'Rect's'

I can post more code, if people can let me know which bits to post, as the code is getting pretty long now.

Comment: Call this `canvas.discardActiveObject()` before removing the object

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is still there.  Still have to press delete twice to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, some other problem in your bigger app is blocking you from delete.
Look at the snippet here, after focusing the snippet iframe, try to press backspace, and the object will be deleted.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
       if (event.key === "Backspace") {
           var currentlySelected = _fabricCanvas.getActiveObject();
           if (currentlySelected) {
               _fabricCanvas.remove(currentlySelected);
           }
       }
    });
    
var _fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100 })
_fabricCanvas.add(rect);
_fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas width=400 height=400 id="c" ></canvas>
```